# Jaxp issue? Can't find org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl using gradle

Tags: gradle, jaxp

I am having trouble getting a class to load in a gradle script.  When I run this code:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
       mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath( group:"xerces", name:'xercesImpl', version:'2.9.1')
    }
}

task hello {
    doLast {
        println 'Hello world!'
        Class testClass = Class.forName("org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl")
        assert testClass: "org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl not found"
        println "found"
    }
}
```

I get this when I run "gradle hello":
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl"

I suspect Jaxp implemenation issues, but don't know much about how jaxp works.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this suffice?

```
import org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl;

buildscript {
    repositories {
       mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath group:"xerces", name:'xercesImpl', version:'2.9.1'
    }
}

task hello {
        println 'Hello world!'
        DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl obj = new DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl()
        // do something with obj
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `getClass().getClassLoader()` instead. `Class.forName()` shouldn't be used at all; it has known problems when called from Java, and is totally unreliable when called from Groovy (you'll typically get the Groovy library's class loader instead of the caller's class loader).